# Undo last Alembic migration

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I created a migration with `alembic revision --autogenerate`, applied it to my development database with `alembic upgrade head`, and then realised it wasn't quite what I wanted.

How can I revert the migration so that I can tweak it and try again?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to go back *one* revision, use [`alembic downgrade`](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html#downgrading) with a [relative migration identifier](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html#relative-migration-identifiers) of -1:

```
alembic downgrade -1
```

This will run the `downgrade()` method of your latest revision and update the `alembic_version` table to indicate the revision you're now at.

If you need to go back multiple migrations, run

```
alembic history
```

to view a list of all the migrations in your project (from newest to oldest), then copy and paste the identifier of the migration you want to go back to:

```
alembic downgrade 8ac14e223d1e
```

There's currently no command to *delete* migrations from your versions directory, so if you want to completely wipe away all trace of your bad migration, you'll need to delete the version file (like `4c009570237e_add_widget_table.py`) manually.

Comment: `FAILED: Relative revision -1 didn't produce 1 migrations` on `alembic downgrade -1`.

Answer (score 7):

Just a note for the answer of Mark Amery: 
If you want to run to downgrade() of a version, you will need to run `alembic downgrade the-version-before-it`, which mean it will revert to the version after the version that you want to downgrade. 
For example, you run `alembic history` and get the below list:

[image]

And assume you want to revert to `cdd99ec41968`, then you will have to run command:

`alembic downgrade 15972effcbd3`

Which is the version before the version that we want to revert.

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Are you sure? It's so counter-intuitive. It's the same as "When you want go to the 7th migration, run command 'go to the 6th migration'".

Comment: Or is it just about "to" or "of", i mean, when we say "downgrade 7th" - we mean "go to the state of 7th migration, canceling 8th migration" - and it's ok. Is it?
But if you saying "downgrade 7th" mean "cancel everything, that 7th migration did and go to the state of the 6th" - than clearly, you just understand it wrong and need to use the-version-before-it.

Answer (score 6):

be careful using alembic

consider next revisions:

```
aaa <-- head
bbb
ccc
ddd <-- base
```

if you execute `alembic upgrade head` you are going to `aaa` revision.

if you execute `alembic downgrade base` you are going to `ddd` revision.

if you execute several times `alembic downgrade -1` eventually you can go from `aaa` to `ddd` revision. Idem to `alembic upgrade +1`

if you only want to iterate between `aaa` and `bbb` revisions I recommend to use:

for upgrade:

```
 alembic upgrade head
```

for downgrade

```
 alembic downgrade head-1
```