# How to run revisions with alembic?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, alembic

I noticed that one of my columns had the wrong name so I changed it. Then I ran alembic upgrade head in the terminal in PyCharm and that didn't work so I dropped that table and another table that I had to drop so I could drop the table I made changes in. I dropped the tables in a sql query. I then tried alembic upgrade head again and that didn't create the tables I had dropped. How do I create the dropped tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alembic keeps the latest applied revision in `alembic_version` table and checks it before upgrading. You need to do a downgrade firstly and then upgrade.

How to do downgrade is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48242325/13782669) answer.

Comment: How do I go about downgrading?

Comment: See this excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48242325/13782669