# Can't rollback a particular Alembic migration by revision ID

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic, schema-migration

I am trying to do schema migration in PostgreSQL via Alembic.

Following this question [Undo last alembic migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242324/undo-last-alembic-migration)

I have 2 migrations with:

```
revision = '0eb4bd9decb0',down_revision = None
--and 
revision = 'bf34bf428845' ,down_revision = '0eb4bd9decb0'
```

So I am successfully run migrations from both migration files by:

```
alembic upgrade 0eb4bd9decb0    
alembic upgrade bf34bf428845
```

Now I have a problem in Downgrading these migration i.e  I want to downgrade migration with `revision= 'bf34bf428845'`

so I write:

```
alembic downgrade bf34bf428845
```

But It is **not Working** and not showing any error

Output of above code:

```
(migration) C:\xampp\htdocs\dbmigration python\migration\db>alembic downgrade bf34bf428845
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

but if I run this code:

```
alembic downgrade -1
```

It is working as expected as per by [Undo last Alembic migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242324/undo-last-alembic-migration)

**My question:**

**How can I downgrade alembic migration by revision id?**

Comment: What happens if you do `alembic downgrade 0eb4bd9decb0` ?

Comment: @GordThompson Sir when I run `alembic downgrade 0eb4bd9decb0` then It will downgrade `bf34bf428845` i.e my table is truncated(I write that in function downgrade in `bf34bf428845`)

Answer (score 1):

When you run

```
alembic upgrade 0eb4bd9decb0
alembic upgrade bf34bf428845
```

which, by the way, is the same as just

```
alembic upgrade bf34bf428845
```

your database will be at revision bf34bf428845. Then if you run

```
alembic downgrade bf34bf428845
```

it will have no effect because the database is already at revision bf34bf428845.

If you want to *undo* the changes that brought you to revision bf34bf428845 you need to downgrade to the revision *before* bf34bf428845, i.e.,

```
alembic downgrade bf34bf428845-1
```

or

```
alembic downgrade 0eb4bd9decb0
```

Comment: Sir when I run `alembic downgrade 0eb4bd9decb0` then It will downgrade `bf34bf428845` i.e my table is truncated(I write that in function downgrade in `bf34bf428845`)

Comment: why this is happening sir?